How to force Remote Desktop Services in administrative mode with RDS role installed
We have some machines installed on Windows Server, where the RDS role is installed, but the license server for the CALs is not configured. The reason behind this is that we use a single deployment image, which is also used on machines where RDS role is required and the license server is then properly configured via GPO.
Now, the problem is that as long as the machines are configured with the RDS role installed, but without the license server, even connections as administrator, which I'd expect to work, are not working. The RD client says

The remote session was disconnected because there are no Remote
Desktop License Servers available to provide a license. Please contact
the server administrator.

I tried enabling the "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session" policy, hoping it would disable the requirement for CALs, but this doesn't seem to be the case.
How can I either force the machines to operate only in administrative mode (allowing the "famous" 2 simultaneous connections with administrative accounts), or to simply disable or uninstall the RDS role? I'd like to achieve that either with GPO (that would be the ideal solution) or programmatically from a remote server (e.g. with Powershell, SC, REG, or any such standard tool, depending on what's needed). I can't find any documentation on MS website about how to do this properly, without having to consume CALs for administrative access.

You can remove roles and features with Powershell, so do that.


The reason behind this is that we use a single deployment image, which is also used on machines where RDS role is required and the license server is then properly configured via GPO.

That isn't a valid reason. Not even close. It's actually a worst practice, as evidenced by the numerous questions here over the years about they are in a jackpot because RDS server stopped working.
RDS requires activation. RDS requires a license server. RDS does not require licenses, but it does require a license server. The license server can even be installed on the same host, and you can have hundreds or even thousands of zombie license services running.
But you cannot not activate RDS or not configure it to use a license server.
The image should not have RDS installed unless it is an RDS-specific image.
